# if one three digit number (0 cannot be left digit) is chosen at random from all those that can be made from this set that are not a multiple of 5.

Tags: probability

Set = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6}

The left digit would have 6 possibilities since 0 cannot be the left digit.
The middle one would have 7 possibilities.
The right digit would have 2 possibilities 0 and 5?

Am I correct? or totally wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @LordSoth if one three digit number (0 cannot be left digit) is chosen at random from all those that can be made from this set that are NOT a multiple of 5. Doesn't say if repetition is allowed

Comment: OK. You got the first two digits right. What are your options for the last digit then?

Comment: just 5 because 0 and 5 are multiples of 5 ?

Comment: You are looking for numbers that ARE NOT multiples of $5$. If you put $0$ or $5$ as the last digit, that number will be a multiple of $5$. Therefore,...

Comment: Ah, OK, you have counted the number of elements in the set $\{1,2,3,4,6\}$ right? Then, you got the answer.

Comment: I meant 5 possibilities

Comment: @MethodManX So, what is your final result then?

Comment: @LordSoth but the question is asking for a probability so will it be 6*7*5 / 6*7*7 ?

Comment: @LordSoth 5/7 right?

Comment: Yes, that is right, the answer should be $5/7$.

Comment: @LordSoth tyvm:)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not allowed to repeat digits, then there are 6 possibilities for the first digit (since it can't be zero), 6 possibilities for the second, and 5 possibilities for the third. If your number has to be a multiple of 5, then there are only 2 possibilities for the third.

Finally, if you're allowed to repeat digits and want a multiple of 5, the numbers are 6, 7, and 2, as you said.

Comment: @ omnomnom the question doesn't say if repetition is allowed

Comment: $6\times 6 \times 2$ will not be the right answer for the number of three-digit numbers that are 1) divisible by $5$ 2) with no digit repetitions and 3) with the first digit not equal to $0$.

Comment: @LordSoth The question doesn't say if repetitions are allowed.

Comment: So that was the question as phrased, then? I think the most likely possibility then, assuming you left out that the number has to be a multiple of 5 and given the ambiguous phrasing, is that repetition is allowed, so that $6\times7\times2$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If repetition is not allowed:

Consider all valid numbers you can form which doesn't have a $0$ in the tens place (and thus doesn't have a $0$ at all). The units digit has $5$ possibilities ($1,2,3,4,6$), the tens digit has $5$ possibilities ($1,2,3,4,5,6$ minus the units digit) and the hundreds digit has $4$ possibilities ($1,2,3,4,5,6$ minus the tens and units digit).

Now consider all numbers with a $0$ in the tens place. The units digit has $5$ possibilities ($1,2,3,4,6$), the tens digit is fixed and the hundreds digit has $5$ possibilities ($1,2,3,4,5,6$ minus the units digit).

So the total is $5\cdot 5\cdot 4 + 5\cdot 5 = 125$.

---

If repetition is allowed, then the first, second and third digits have $6$, $7$ and $5$ possibilities respectively. So the total is $6\cdot 7\cdot 5=210$.

Comment: @ Alraxite hows does the last digit have 5 possibilities if the number has to be a multiple of 5?

Comment: @MethodManX Your current question does not restrict the three digit number to be a multiple of something. If it has to be a multiple of $5$, then please specify it in your question.

Comment: @ Alraxite sorry yes you are right correct answer

Comment: Assuming we are allowed to repeat digits the last digit is **anything but** 0 and 5 as we are told it's **not** a multiple of 5

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to repeat digits:
There are 6 possibilities for the first digit since you cant pick zero
There are 7 possibilities for the second digit.
There are 5 possibilities for the last as it cant be 0 or 5

Making $6 \times 7 \times 5 = 210 $ possible numbers